# Decimal data type and insertion error

Tags: mysql

I have a table with field named `num` which is `decimal(3,3)`
when I try to insert a value such as `-1.0` I get 
`Error code 1264. Out of range value for column 'num' at row 1`

Can you please specify why my value is out of range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not the sign.  The problem is the `(3, 3)`.  This specifies three digits of precision and scale -- so all three digits are to the right of the decimal point.

Use `decimal(4, 3)`.